# How to structure an answer to a question that asks to prove whether a set is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the set $W=\{ (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;:\; a^2 = b^2\}$, I need to prove that it is a subspace of  $\mathbb R^2$. To me this question seems intuitive, since I know that subspaces of  $\mathbb R^2$ are essentially any lines through the origin. I also know that subspaces are closed under addition, multiplication and contain the zero vector. The function $y^2 = x^2$ spans the entirety of the xy plane so in a sense is that not a proof for it being a subspace? How would I structure a foolproof answer to this question? Thank you.

Comment: The points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are both in $W$ but $(1,1)+(1,-1)=(2,0)$ isn't in $W$. Therefore $W$ isn't closed under the aditon of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: By the way, there is a typo in the definition of $W$. You wrote $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. It should be $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbf{2}}$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you I have now corrected it.

Comment: James, do you know what $W$ looks like?

Comment: @TonyK Would it look like the function $y^2 = x^2$?

Comment: The set $\{y^2 = x^2\}$ is a union of two lines $\{y=x\}\cup \{y=-x\}$. The union of vector spaces is not generally a vector space.

Comment: But James, what does $y^2=x^2$ look like?? (It's not a function, by the way.)